# Merging files in Sourcesafe

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

All,

I currently have two projects that are under SourceSafe that I am unable to migrate to our SVN server for a number of reasons.

However I am currently in the process of trying to merge fixes from one project into the other.

I know Sourcesafe isn't the best at this but the process I am going through just now is particularly tedious

1. Compare the files identyfying the
   changes I need to merge.
2. copy and
   paste the relevant changes into the
   desired project
3. Test
4. Commit

This doesn't seem too bad but with multiple changes and multiple files that need reviewed this is becoming a nightmare.

Does anyone have any other methods to carry this out??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be worthwhile to check out the different versions and use a 3rd-party tool to merge them.  Take a look at kdiff3 ([http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net)) -- it runs on linux or Windows and will merge up to 3 different versions quite intelligently.  This allows you to compare two developers' changes to a common base version.

Another useful tool is kompare, which does an admirable job of highlighting very specific differences between two files.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, merging in VSS is so bad, I personally would check in both versions of your project into SVN and do a diff between the two directory trees to come up with your differences.

That will at least make Step #1 really easy.  If you aren't allowed to do this on your SVN server, create a local repository on your disk using TortoiseSVN temporarily to accomplish the task.

Answer (score -1):

winmerge can combine with sourcesafe.
support folder comparision.